# Resolve error - can't find function ezANOVA?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a Repeated Measures ANOVA on R used the `ezANOVA()` function. I've installed the package and added it into my script. When I go to run it, I get the error that R cannot find function ezANOVA.

I've updated my R Script and R software, but I'm not sure what else to do.

```
model = ezANOVA(data, bsi_rt, subject, within=time, detailed=TRUE, return_aov=TRUE)
```

Comment: do you have the `devtools` library installed?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an issues with the version of `Rcpp` you may have. Here is the fix:

Install `devtools` (You can skip this step if you have `devtools` installed):

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

Update `Rcpp` to the most current version (0.12.18, released Oct, 2019)

```
devtools::install_version("Rcpp", "0.12.18")
```

Re-install the `ez` library and run your code:

```
install.packages("ez")

library(ez)
model = ezANOVA(data, bsi_rt, subject, within=time, detailed=TRUE, return_aov=TRUE)
```